# Sorting not a standard LinkedList

Tags: java

I have a `LinkedList<Individual>` where `Individual` is a class that has a field `processorTime`.
It is needed to sort this LinkedList (descending order) basing on a function `estimate(processorTime)` which returns integers.

Please, tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Where does the estimate method reside? inside the individual object? It does make sense for me for you to use a linkedlist since you obviously does not want to retain the order for which the objects are inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this guide here:

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/comparators.html

Quotations from the site:

> The java.util.Comparator interface can be used to create objects to pass to sort methods or
>   sorting data structures. A Comparator must define a compare function which takes two
>   Objects and returns a -1, 0, or 1

Pasted code:

```
// File: arrays/filelist/Filelistsort.java
// Purpose: List contents of user home directory.
//          Demonstrates use of Comparators to sort the
//          same array by two different criteria.
// Author: Fred Swartz 2006-Aug-23  Public domain.

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.io.*;

public class Filelistsort {

    //======================================================= main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //... Create comparators for sorting.
        Comparator<File> byDirThenAlpha = new DirAlphaComparator();
        Comparator<File> byNameLength   = new NameLengthComparator();

        //... Create a File object for user directory.
        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        File[] children = dir.listFiles();

        System.out.println("Files by directory, then alphabetical");
        Arrays.sort(children, byDirThenAlpha);
        printFileNames(children);

        System.out.println("Files by length of name (long first)");
        Arrays.sort(children, byNameLength);
        printFileNames(children);
    }

    //============================================= printFileNames
    private static void printFileNames(File[] fa){
        for (File oneEntry : fa) {
            System.out.println("   " + oneEntry.getName());
        }
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////// DirAlphaComparator
// To sort directories before files, then alphabetically.
class DirAlphaComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    // Comparator interface requires defining compare method.
    public int compare(File filea, File fileb) {
        //... Sort directories before files,
        //    otherwise alphabetical ignoring case.
        if (filea.isDirectory() && !fileb.isDirectory()) {
            return -1;

        } else if (!filea.isDirectory() && fileb.isDirectory()) {
            return 1;

        } else {
            return filea.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(fileb.getName());
        }
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////// NameLengthComparator
// To sort by length of file/directory name (longest first).
class NameLengthComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    // Comparator interface requires defining compare method.
    public int compare(File filea, File fileb) {
        int comp = fileb.getName().length() - filea.getName().length();
        if (comp != 0) {
            //... If different lengths, we're done.
            return comp;
        } else {
            //... If equal lengths, sort alphabetically.
            return filea.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(fileb.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @robbrit, SO best practice is to quote relevant material to avoid needing to follow a (potentially stale, for later readers) link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question .  See also extensive discussion on @Jon Skeet's blog: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I'm an SO newbie! I'll edit the answer to include it.

Comment: @robbrit: No problem, I think the prescription "answer the question for everybody, and for all time, not just for the immediate questioner" is one of the things that makes SO great.

Comment: Skeet's entry on writing good questions is also quite useful... http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Also note that the statement quotes is not precisely correct.  The contract for `compare()` talks about signed integers.  Using -1,0,1 is just a common convention.  See the contract for `compare()` here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the `LinkedList` is not standard, or the sort order based on processor time is not standard?

If the latter, then all you need to do is use [`Collections.sort(list,comparator)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and provide an appropriate implementation of [`Comparator<NodeType>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your list.   See also ["implementing `compareTo()`"](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10) which gives some good related guidance.

Post the code for your node and the desired output, and we can give you more specific direction.

```
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<Individual>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(final Individual i1, final Individual i2) {
     return i1.processorTime - i2.processorTime;
  } 

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object foo) {
    return false; // doesn't matter, but false is better
  }
});
```

Comment: I mean that my LinkedList is not, for example, LinkedList<Integer>. I knew nothing about comparators. Starting to learn them now =)

Answer (score 2):

```
Collections.sort(linkedList, new Comparator<Individual>() {
     int compare(Individual i1, Individual i2) {
       ...
     }
   });
```